# PHP curl getting unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: php, php-curl

I have am trying to make a curl call via PHP 
if i set the CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to true i get the error

> CURL ERROR: #60 - SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer
>   certificate

I think i have done all the steps mentioned in all the associated articles

My php.ini (version 5.6.11) i have set

```
curl.cainfo=D:\php\cacert.pem
openssl.cafile=D:\php\cacert.pem
```

the cacert.pem is the latest on https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem

the curl code looks like

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, ini_get('curl.cainfo'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $header);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
$curlErr = curl_errno($ch);
if($curlErr){
    echo("(".__LINE__.") "
            .__FILE__." -->"
            .__METHOD__." CURL ERROR: #"
            . curl_errno($ch)
            ." - ". print_r(curl_error($ch),true)."\n");
}
$myfile = fopen( ini_get('curl.cainfo') , "r") ; 
echo fread($myfile,filesize(ini_get('curl.cainfo')));
fclose($myfile);
```

i can read and display the contents of the file ini_get('curl.cainfo')

i can also read the contents of the file

Thanks for any help

Comment: Read permission problems eliminated?

Comment: updated the code to read the file and the contents of the cainfo file display , so permissions are ok